# What is the common way to say "no javascript" in the request header?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, header

I want to tell the server that the browser does not support javascript.

What's the most common approach to do that? (What header is most common?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The HTTP protocol doesn't define any such header. So you could use a custom one. Like:

```
X-JAVASCRIPT-ENABLED: false
```

But of course you could have as well used any other header you liked. And by the way may I ask why would the server would care whether the client supports javascript or not? I mean that's the client responsibility. The `<noscript>` tag is a good way to provide an alternative contents to clients not supporting javascript.

Comment: If the server knows javascript is not enabled it can reply with a non javascript version.

Comment: If such header were standardized, servers could save a little bit of bandwidth and not have to send both `<script>` and `<noscript>` versions of a page.

Answer (score 2):

@Darin's answer used to be correct, today one would use `Content-Security-Policy: sandbox (...)`

i would recommend just
`Content-Security-Policy: sandbox;` as the safest option, but that will disallow much more than just scripts; to allow "everything except scripts", it would probably be:

```
Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-downloads-without-user-activation allow-forms allow-modals allow-orientation-lock allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-storage-access-by-user-activation allow-top-navigation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation;
```

with the only missing value being `allow-scripts`

(but again, i recommend just enabling all the sandboxing features, eg `Content-Security-Policy: sandbox;`)

Comment: Great news. I wish they would cater a bit better for the no-JS case though with something more succinct, since that list of allows will just have to be increased more and more as new capabilities are inevitably added. MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆再教育营六四事件法轮功郝海东 agreed. maybe `Content-Security-Policy: sandbox-inverse allow-scripts` or some such

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are ascking about field that should be set normaly when request sent by javascript

```
 X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
```

anyway this method doesn't work everywhere and everytime, so you can use in on your own risk.