# Request a no-javascript variant of a website

Tags: php, apache, http, curl, webserver

I read in and parse a website using PHP & cURL. This website sometimes sent a javascript-enabled sourcecode and sometimes a javascript-disabled sourcecode. This makes parsing very hard as i would have to look for both variants.

Is there any way to say "I have no javascript enabled" or better what are signals, the other side is looking for to decide to sent a javscript-enabled version or not.

*I know that curl operates serverside and can not parse javascript, i simply want to send some signals to the server that say "Please send me the javascript-disabled version"*.

Comment: What about relying on whatever is within `<noscript>`?

Comment: The information i need isn't contained in any noscript-tag

Comment: There is no 'standard' way to do it. eg http headers. Its upto the site in question to decide how do to do it. Perhaps its jsut looking at the useragent, or perhaps its guessing. Mybe it has some query parameter - but again it would be specific to th site in question. so we can help

Comment: In my case, the User-Agent did the trick. User-Agent String of old browsers (IE7, FF 2, FF3) are working well and always give me the results without javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try and send the following header;

```
X-JAVASCRIPT-ENABLED: false
```

Comment: If this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6272113/499214 is your source, then you'd be _very_ lucky to find a server that actually knows this header.

Comment: Out of ten pages on google search for the phrase "x-javascript-enabled", only two refer to this header: The one I linked (~ page 4) and this very answer (~ page 8).

Comment: Granted it is a long shot. But it is a start for the OP?